# why i keep getting duplicated lists in my recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

Can anyone show me what have I done wrong here, I am using `recyclerView` with livedata every time I launch the app it spawns with a random list and sometimes its full of duplicates.
Here is the code that assigns data to the adapter :

```
adapter = new PaymentsByDateParentAdapter(getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SchoolViewModel.class);

    viewModel.getAllPayments().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Payment>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Payment> payments) {
            for (Payment i : payments) {
                datesWithDupes.add(i.getPaymentDate());
            }
            for (String i : datesWithDupes) {
                if (!datesWithoutDupes.contains(i)) {
                    datesWithoutDupes.add(i);
                }
            }
            for (String date : datesWithoutDupes) {
                viewModel.getPaymentsByDate(date).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Payment>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(List<Payment> payments) {
                        PaymentByDate paymentByDate = new PaymentByDate(date, payments);
                        paymentByDateList.add(paymentByDate);
                        adapter.setPayments(paymentByDateList);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the arraylists `datesWithDupes`, `paymentByDateList` and `datesWithoutDupes` before the for loops.

```
datesWithDupes.clear();
datesWithoutDupes.clear();
paymentByDateList.clear();

for (Payment i : payments) {
    datesWithDupes.add(i.getPaymentDate());
}
for (String i : datesWithDupes) {
    if (!datesWithoutDupes.contains(i)) {
        datesWithoutDupes.add(i);
    }
}
for (String date : datesWithoutDupes) {
    viewModel.getPaymentsByDate(date).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Payment>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Payment> payments) {
            PaymentByDate paymentByDate = new PaymentByDate(date, payments);
            paymentByDateList.add(paymentByDate);
            adapter.setPayments(paymentByDateList);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the try, but this hasn't solved my problem, for some reasons i think the problem may be related to using live data